# tinynav.js is not working for ie8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, menu, drupal-7

I am using Drumal to make my site and for theme I used "Omega kickstart Subtheme". I have installed Tinynav.js module and its not working in "IE 8 AND BELOW BROWSERS", whereas its working in all other browsers including "IE 11". Can any one help me out in solving this issue? Thank you.

PS: Some people might say that tinynav.js is not working IE 8 AND BELOW browsers because they doesn't support css media queries. But, I have worked around that issue and all my css media queries are working greatly in all browsers including all versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Tried https://drupal.org/project/responsive_menus ?

The "Simple" and "Sidr" styles work with IE8.

Turn off "absolute position" if using "Simple" style.

They use JS to check window size rather than media queries.